# Firebase Response has HTML Tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, react-native

I am pulling from a firebase database which contains HTML elements and inline styling. The response would look something like this:

`<p class=\"paragraph ng-attr-widget\" style=\"text-align: left;\"><span class=\"ng-directive ng-binding\" style=\"color: #ffffff; font-size: 14pt;\">Candy canes lemon drops cheesecake...etc`

My question is, how would I remove all of the html tags and inline styling from the response? That way I can get something like:

Candy canes lemon drops cheesecake and so forth.

I am using React Native!

Comment: Would it not be a lot more efficient to store that text as a property in the database (if you're doing the storage side of this too)?

Comment: I am not doing the storage part of it. If I was, I would have done it differently...

Answer (score 0):

```js
data = "<p class=\"paragraph ng-attr-widget\" style=\"text-align: left;\"><span class=\"ng-directive ng-binding\" style=\"color: #ffffff; font-size: 14pt;\">Candy canes lemon drops cheesecake...etc";

console.log(data.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, ""));
```

Comment: Okay this eliminated most of my issue, but I am also getting &nbsp; pop up everywhere.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags